# passing output from a script to my .profile

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, .profile

I have a *Script* inside my *Home Directory*.  The *Script* just provides a single message as an output. I'm trying to have my: `.profile` execute the *Script* so I can see this message.

I'm trying to use my profile as a log.  So I can find the error.

My question is this, **Since the *Script* invokes a basic `echo` request do I have to pass my message into a variable so it can be passed to that `.profile`?**

When I implement `ISPOD = Home/isProd export ISPROD` to source it to my `.profile` the message does not exists.  How can I solve this issue.

Comment: Make sure you have no spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to consider here.
When you do

```
ISPROD=$HOME/isProd
```

the actual content of your variable is the isProd path, and not its output.
If you want to execute the command and catch the output then try $(command) or `command`.

```
ISPROD=$($HOME/isProd)
```

or

```
ISPROD=`$HOME/isProd`
```

at this point ISPROD will contain the output of the script. But you still need to show the content, hence you need to add

```
echo "$ISPROD"
```

But the same behaviour can be achieved just by executing the command without capturing the output and then echoing it. 
Try with putting directly

```
$HOME/isProd
```

in the .profile and source it. 
Also, make sure that .profile is the actual file that the shell sources at login time (bash for example uses .bash_profile).